# Google map v3 won't load in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, google-maps, internet-explorer-9

I am having a problem loading a google map v3 in Internet explorer 9. Chrome and Firefox load it perfectly, but IE9 doesn't show it at all. I have this function:

```
function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.109742, 20.462222),
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
```

which I am calling here:

```
<body onload="load()">
```

At the beginning of my page I have an "if" clause which recognizes browsers:

```
<?php if ( preg_match( '/MSIE/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) ) { ?>
    <link href="CSS/stylemapaIE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<?php } elseif ( preg_match( '/Firefox/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) ) { ?>
    <link href="CSS/stylemapaMF.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<?php } else { ?>
    <link href="CSS/stylemapa.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<?php } ?>
```

and uses three different css stylesheets. You can see the page at http://jedanzasve.rs/Test/mapaponuda.php Any thoughts?

Comment: Your map appears to load for me in IE9, though there are a couple undefined variables which also don't exist in Chrome either.

Comment: There don't seem to be any, is there any particular tab I should be looking?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw one, it wasn't there because I opened the console after the refreshing of the page. I have this: SCRIPT5007: The value of the property 'load' is null or undefined, not a Function object 
mapaponuda.php, line 203 character 1

Comment: `GIcon` and `GBrowserIsCompatible` are both `undefined` in IE9 as well as in Chrome. However, the map is loading for me in IE9.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: Cleared the cache now, worked like a charm - there are still errors, but the map is loading. Thanks a lot, the simplest solutions are usually the ones that do the trick  :)

Comment: Glad to have been of help. I've migrated this advice into an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map loads for me in IE9 (Browser Mode: IE9), as well as in Chrome. However you do have some `undefined` variables cropping up in the console. This suggests to me that you have not properly referenced all of your resources, or you have not referenced them in the proper order. Of course another possibility is that you're simply working off cached files.

Clear your cache, double-check your resources, and their dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not using IE 9's Compatibility View. TO verify this Open Developer Tools and look at the two dropdowns on the right of the menu bar, if it says IE9 Compatibility View change it to Internet Explorer 9 and Internet Explorer 9 Standards.

To open Developer Tools

> Press F12

or

> Tools > Select F12 Developer Tools

Comment: +1 Checking the site in IE9 Compat View does give me the error the OP reported seeing.

Comment: I wasn't using Compatibility View, but thanks for the advice anyway. The cache was the problem, and some bad dependencies.